# When a regular $F_{\sigma}$ set open?

Tags: general-topology

> A **regular $F_{\sigma}$ set** is a set $S \subset X$ such that S is a union of a sequence of open sets whose interiors contain $S$ i.e. $S=\cup_{1}^{\infty} F_n= \cup_{1}^{\infty} {F_n}^{\circ}$.

My question is when an open set is regular $F_{\sigma}$ set?

AS clearly every regular $F_{\sigma}$ set open, does the converse hold in all metrizable spaces or some other particular type of topological spaces? Also is there any relation between $F_{\sigma}$ set and regular $F_{\sigma}$ set?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that in every metric space $(X,d)$ this is correct, for if $O$ is an open set, then it is $F_{\sigma}$-set, by setting for example, $F_n=\{ x\in O: d(x, X\setminus O) \geq \frac{1}{n} \}$. Then $int(F_n)=\{ x\in O: d(x, X\setminus O) > \frac{1}{n} \}$ and thus $$O=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}F_n =\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}int(F_n)$$

Comment: They way you define a regular $F_\sigma$ is just saying that is an open set. 

So you must mean something different?

Comment: Or are your $F_n$ closed instead? that would make more sense as they cannot be open in your definition (that would add nothing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the correct definition

> A **regular $F_{\sigma}$ set** is a set $S \subset X$ such that S is a union of a sequence of *closed* sets $F_n$ whose interiors contain $S$ i.e. $S=\cup_{1}^{\infty} F_n= \cup_{1}^{\infty} {F_n}^{\circ}$.

Then it's obvious that a regular $F_\sigma$ set is in particular an $F_\sigma$ (as witnessed by $S=\bigcup_n F_n$) and open (because $S=\bigcup_n F_n^\circ$, a union of opens). Not all open $F_\sigma$ sets will be regular $F_\sigma$ in general but as noted in the comments, this *is* the case in any metrisable space $X$, using the sets $F_n = \{x \in O\mid d(x,O^\complement) \ge \frac1n\}$ for an open set $O$. Also in regular hereditarily Lindelöf spaces this will be the case.

Comment: Thanks. You are right and makes sense.